# How to check a dijit checkbox with javascript

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I am working a very old codebase.  It is using an old version of dijit, so I am having a hard time finding out how to do what I need to do.

There is a dijitcheckbox on a modal, it uses `aria-pressed` instead of `checked`, I need to check this box when a user selects a value elsewhere, but I can't get the box to check.

Answer (score 0):

depends a bit on how old the dojo version is....

usually you can do something like

```
var w = dijit.byId(myWidgetId);
// or var w = dijit.byNode(checkboxDomNode);
w.set('checked', true);
```

for dojo 1.3 you need to use more specific functions:

```
w.setChecked(true)
```

the aria-pressed should be an additional attribute for screenreader, there will be a hidden "real" checkbox that is checked.

btw., the dojo api documentation even has entries for v1.3: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dijit/form/CheckBox

Comment: I tried this, issue is that I need the visible box to become checked.  As is the checkbox stays empty then when you mouse over it it checks.  I need it to check as soon as the option is selected and not when the user mouses over it.  Everything else works fine just need this to visibly check.

Comment: usually (tm) the widget.set(property, value) method does all the magic to change the visiual representation according to the value. if the dojo version is < 1.5, you can try w.attr(attribute, value) instead. but maybe there is some strange sideeffect because you are in a modal dialog(?) - you could also try to force a new layout run on layout widget that has the checkox on it (layoutthingie.layout() or lt._layoutChildren() )

Comment: it is version 1.3.3, the w.attr(atrribute, value) didn't work because I wasn't sure what attribute I was looking for checked was not defined.  
 (layoutthingie.layout() or lt._layoutChildren() )  that is the first I've seen that.  Zend 1.8 is using this version of digit so I'm not sure how to go about the layoutChildren and such or if it would even apply.